# Posiciones de Objetos Dinamicos C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema que no consigo solucionar.

Como puedo hacer para que si tengo por ejemplo 5 imágenes (introducidas por código) y cada una de esas tiene su posición, ahora viene el problema, quiero añadir 1 nueva imagen y quiero que la imagen nueva se coloque delante de la 1, la 1 pasa a ser la 2 y así sucesivamente, es fácil cuando tienes pocas imágenes, puedes hacerlo tu manualmente, el problema es que tengo que poner mas de 400 imágenes. Y tengo filas de 5 imágenes, quiero agregar 1 sin tener que mover las 400 que van detrás, como lo podría hacer? Llevo días rompiéndome la cabeza, cabe destacar que mi nivel de programación no es muy alto.

Uso Visual Studio 2013, C#.

Dejo fragmento de codigo de la creaccion de las imagenes.

```
        IMG1.Image = Properties.Resources.C367;
        IMG1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(177, 236);
        IMG1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        IMG1.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        TabPage32.Controls.Add(IMG1);
        IMG1.Top = 30 + 250 * (PT - 1);
        IMG1.Left = 50;
        IMG1.MouseClick += IMG1_MouseClick;

        IMG2.Image = Properties.Resources.C368;
        IMG2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(177, 236);
        IMG2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        IMG2.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        TabPage32.Controls.Add(IMG2);
        IMG2.Top = 30 + 250 * (PT - 1);
        IMG2.Left = 250;
        IMG2.MouseClick += IMG2_MouseClick;

        IMG3.Image = Properties.Resources.C369;
        IMG3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(177, 236);
        IMG3.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        IMG3.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        TabPage32.Controls.Add(IMG3);
        IMG3.Top = 30 + 250 * (PT - 1);
        IMG3.Left = 450;
        IMG3.MouseClick += IMG3_MouseClick;

        IMG4.Image = Properties.Resources.C370;
        IMG4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(177, 236);
        IMG4.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        IMG4.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        TabPage32.Controls.Add(IMG4);
        IMG4.Top = 30 + 250 * (PT - 1);
        IMG4.Left = 650;
        IMG4.MouseClick += IMG4_MouseClick;

        IMG5.Image = Properties.Resources.C371;
        IMG5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(177, 236);
        IMG5.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        IMG5.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        TabPage32.Controls.Add(IMG5);
        IMG5.Top = 30 + 250 * (PT - 1);
        IMG5.Left = 850;
        IMG5.MouseClick += IMG5_MouseClick;
```

Si en PT le restamos 1 bajarían hacia abajo las 5 imágenes pudiendo poner 5 mas arriba.
El problema como digo está al querer poner menos de 5.
Pudiendo quedar la nueva imagen al lado de la IMG1 que ahora pasa a estar donde IMG2 y así sucesivamente.

No dibujo nada bien jaja.

[image: Ejemplo]

Gracias.

Comment: Cual es el tipo de data de IMG1?

Comment: es una aplicacion winform? o usas WPF, o es web

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Posiciones de Objetos dinamicas C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/294608/posiciones-de-objetos-dinamicas-c)

Comment: Winform, IMGx = picturebox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la idea es no complicarte con el posicionamiento ayudate con el control

[TableLayoutPanel Control (Windows Forms)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-windows-forms)

con este podras generar una tabla con celdas donde ubicar los controles y moverlos usando la posicion de las celdas en lugar de coordenadas

[Procedimiento para delimitar y acoplar controles secundarios en un control TableLayoutPanel](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-anchor-and-dock-child-controls-in-a-tablelayoutpanel-control)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como observaras posicionar un control en una celda es mucho mas simple para moverla que hacerlo con corrdenadas
como observaras

Comment: Eso esta bien, el problema es que hay mas de 400 imagenes, y el TableLayout tiene un tamaño, si que puedes agregar muy facil pero no caben todas en un espacio de por ejemplo 1000x700.

Comment: estas seguro que vas a poder mover de forma fluida ese numero de imagenes? yo no lo creo, deberias pensar en mostrarlas paginadas de alguna forma para que carguen en grupos de 20, pero sigo pensando que con un contorl de layout el posicionamiento es miles de veces mas simple que usando coordenadas

Comment: por el momento están puestas así 370 imagenes, funciona bien y fluido, alomejor, esta bien de poner paginas o cambiar el tamaño vertical si se añaden 5 imagenes mas.

Comment: También esta el problema que si tienen que ser paginas, de por ejemplo 100 imagenes, como se hace para pasar de la imagen 101 de la pag 1 a la pagina 2, ahí tambien tendriamos un problema.

Comment: De todas formas de esta manera solo puedo agregar columnas y filas, no puedo agregar una sola celda.

Comment: para que quieres agregar una sola celda? si defines que vas a mostrar en el ancho del form digamos 5 columnas, despeus vas creando filas de 5 columnas y moviendo sobre estas, si alguna queda vacia porque no tiene la cantidad de imagenes no afecta en nada

Comment: Quiero agregar una sola celda en la parte superior para que la fila 1 quden 5 imagenes que no qude 1 y luego las otras 4 vacias, no me importa que queden vacias en la ultima fila, pero la primera es esencial que este completa.

Comment: Estoy probando unas cosas pero no se como cambiar unas cosas 
`Pos1.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(IMAGEN.ToString());
Pos1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(177, 236);
Pos1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
Pos1.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
TabPageM22.Controls.Add(Pos1);
Pos1.Top = 30 + 250 * (PT - 0);
Pos1.Left = 50;
Pos1.MouseClick += COLOCAR STRING AQUI_MouseClick;
        }`

Como pongo un string dentro el evento? el string cambia por lo tanto el evento también.

`Pos1.MouseClick += COLOCAR STRING AQUI_MouseClick;`

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo tengo solucionado, comparto el codigo por si alguien le sirve, Saludos y Gracias a tod@s.

Añadimos un tableLayoutPanel y le asignamos su tamaño.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ImageneD();
        SizeD();
    }

    PictureBox IMG1 = new PictureBox();
    PictureBox IMG2 = new PictureBox();
    PictureBox IMG3 = new PictureBox();
    PictureBox IMG4 = new PictureBox();
    PictureBox IMG5 = new PictureBox();
    int NIMGs = 5;//Por cada imagen sumamos 1.
    void ImagenesD()
    {
        //IMG6.Image = Properties.Resources.C7;
        //IMG6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(177, 236);
        //IMG6.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        //IMG6.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        //this.Controls.Add(IMG6);
        //IMG6.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
        //tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(IMG6, (NIMGs - 6), 0);

        IMG5.Image = Properties.Resources.C6;
        IMG5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(177, 236);
        IMG5.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        IMG5.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        this.Controls.Add(IMG5);
        //cambiamos el this por el tableLayoutPanel si no lo llamamos desde el inicio.
        IMG5.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(IMG5, (NIMGs - 5), 0);

        IMG4.Image = Properties.Resources.C5;
        IMG4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(177, 236);
        IMG4.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        IMG4.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        this.Controls.Add(IMG4);
        IMG4.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(IMG4, (NIMGs - 4), 0);

        IMG3.Image = Properties.Resources.C4;
        IMG3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(177, 236);
        IMG3.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        IMG3.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        this.Controls.Add(IMG3);
        IMG3.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(IMG3, (NIMGs - 3), 0);

        IMG2.Image = Properties.Resources.C3;
        IMG2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(177, 236);
        IMG2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        IMG2.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        this.Controls.Add(IMG2);
        IMG2.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(IMG2, (NIMGs - 2), 0);

        IMG1.Image = Properties.Resources.C2;
        IMG1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(177, 236);
        IMG1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        IMG1.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        this.Controls.Add(IMG1);
        IMG1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(IMG1, (NIMGs - 1), 0);
    }

    void SizeD()
    {
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 4;//Cambiamos dependiendo de cuantas filas quieres, tambien pueden ponerse columnas.
        TableLayoutRowStyleCollection styles = tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles;
        foreach (RowStyle style in styles)
        {
            style.SizeType = (SizeType.Absolute);
            style.Height = 236;//Tamaño altura imagen.
        }
        tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new Size(tableLayoutPanel1.Size.Width, tableLayoutPanel1.Size.Height * tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount);
    }
}
```